# What is the word for a personality quality or gesture that someone does over and over?

Tags: word-request, american-english, informal-language

I'm currently stumped trying to remember the word for when someone does something or says something in a consistent manner as part of their personality. For example, my friend Sam always shrugs his shoulders high and smiles when my coworkers ask him redundant questions. I wanna say that's his personality quip or gesture but I know that's not the right word. I feel like it starts with a P but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I like this one best

> [mannerism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mannerism)
>   : a person's particular way of talking or moving

But some other possibilities include

1. practice
2. pattern
3. propensity
4. habit
5. quirk
6. idiosyncrasy

Comment: Can you add summaries of the other words as well?

Answer (score 1):

The word that I would use is

> [mannerism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mannerism?q=Mannerism) - something that a person does repeatedly with their face, hands, or voice, and that they may not realize they are doing.

If it is particularly unusual, you could call it a **quirk** or **foible**

> [quirk](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quirk) - an unusual habit or part of someone's personality, or something that is strange and unexpected
>
> [foible](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foible) - a strange habit or characteristic that is seen as not important and not harming anyone